# Alternative for while loops in tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, while-loop

I am trying to make an alarm application: the alarm should go off at a pre-set time. The piece of code I have works completely fine without tkinter, but with tkinter it doesn't work at all. 
In the original piece of code there is a while loop and I've noticed and read that that can't be combined with tkinter. I decided to get rid of the loop, but now the alarm goes off immediately when I enter a time.

I've read about using r.after(time_ms, function()). But I don't know how to implement that properly in my code. I've read that it has to be at the end of the function and before r.mainloop(), but I couldn't get it to work. Can somebody please help me? Thank you very much!
I've read a lot or stackoverflow posts about this, but I am not experienced enough to get it to work with those answers. :(

```
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime, date
import time
from pygame import mixer

r = tk.Tk()
r.title('Smart Watch')

def alarm_sound():
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('Wecker-sound.mp3')

def end():
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.stop()

def display_output():
    hour = entry_hour.get()
    int_hour = int(hour)
    minute = entry_minute.get()
    int_minute = int(minute)
    second = entry_second.get()
    int_second = int(second)
    confirmation_message = ('Alarm has been set for ' + hour + ':' +
                             minute + ':' + second + '.')
    text_label['text'] = confirmation_message


    if (time.localtime().tm_hour == hour and
            time.localtime().tm_min == entry_minute.get() and
                time.localtime().tm_sec == entry_second.get()):
        alarm_sound()
        mixer.music.play()

message = tk.Label(r, text='What is the alarm message you\'d like to receive when the alarm goes off?',
                  font=('Roboto-regular', 12), fg='black')
message.pack()
entry_message = tk.Entry(r, width=45)
entry_message.pack()
enter_hour = tk.Label(r, text='Enter the hour for the alarm to go off: ',
                        font=('Roboto-regular', 12), fg='black')
enter_hour.pack()
entry_hour = tk.Entry(r, width=10)
entry_hour.pack()
enter_minute = tk.Label(r, text='Enter the minute for the alarm to go off: ',
                        font=('Roboto-regular', 12), fg='black')
enter_minute.pack()
entry_minute = tk.Entry(r, width=10)
entry_minute.pack()
enter_second = tk.Label(r, text='Enter the second for the alarm to go off: ',
                    font=('Roboto-regular', 12), fg='black')
enter_second.pack()
entry_second = tk.Entry(r, width=10)
entry_second.pack()
text_label = tk.Label(r, font=('Roboto-regular', 12, 'bold'),
                      fg='tomato')
text_label.pack()
submit_button = tk.Button(r, text='Submit',
                          fg='black', width=30, height=2, relief='groove',
                          cursor='hand2', command=display_output)
submit_button.pack()
snooze_button = tk.Button(r, text='Snooze alarm',
                          fg='black',
                          width=30, height=2, relief='groove',
                          cursor='hand2', command=end)
snooze_button.pack()


r.mainloop()

# The original code without tkinter has the while loop like this:
while True:
    if time.localtime().tm_hour == hr and time.localtime().tm_min == mn and time.localtime().tm_sec == sc:
        print(message)
        break
alarm_Sound()
mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: example which uses `after` to change time in clock: [furas/tkitner/clock-function](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py) It doesn't use `while True` but it use `after` in `update_time` to run again `update_time` so it works like loop.

Comment: BTW: `after(...)` as second argument needs function's name without `()`

Comment: Thank you. I've tried the function's name without (), but then i get an error that says 'bad argument: must be cancel, idle, info, or an integer'.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should use global variables to keep values from `Entry` and use them later in function which check time. This function should use `after` to run its again when there is no time for alarm. It should also skip `after()` to stop checking time.

```
def display_output():
    global int_hour
    global int_minute
    global int_second

    hour = entry_hour.get()
    int_hour = int(hour)

    minute = entry_minute.get()
    int_minute = int(minute)

    second = entry_second.get()
    int_second = int(second)

    text_label['text'] = 'Alarm has been set for {}:{}:{}.'.format(hour, minute, second)
    # start checking time    
    check_time()


def check_time():

    dt = time.localtime()

    if (dt.tm_hour == int_hour and dt.tm_min == int_minute and dt.tm_sec == int_second):
        alarm_sound()
        mixer.music.play()
    else:
        r.after(1000, check_time) # check it again after 1000ms but only if it doesn't play sound
```

---

Code would need other global variables to control if alarm in running when you stop it and when you try to set it again.

---

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, date
import tkinter as tk
from pygame import mixer

# --- functions ---

def alarm_sound():
    global running_alarm

    running_alarm = True

    mixer.music.load('Wecker-sound.mp3')

def end():
    global running_alarm

    if running_alarm:
        running_alarm = False
        mixer.music.stop()
        text_label['text'] = ''

def display_output():
    global int_hour
    global int_minute
    global int_second

    hour = entry_hour.get()
    int_hour = int(hour)

    minute = entry_minute.get()
    int_minute = int(minute)

    second = entry_second.get()
    int_second = int(second)

    confirmation_message = ('Alarm has been set for {}:{}:{}.'.format(hour, minute, second))

    text_label['text'] = confirmation_message

    check_time()


def check_time():

    dt = time.localtime()

    if (dt.tm_hour == int_hour and dt.tm_min == int_minute and dt.tm_sec == int_second):
        checking_time = False # stop l
        alarm_sound()
        mixer.music.play()
    else:
        r.after(1000, check_time)

# --- main ---

running_alarm = False # default value at start

mixer.init()


r = tk.Tk()
r.title('Smart Watch')

message = tk.Label(r, text='What is the alarm message you\'d like to receive when the alarm goes off?',
                  font=('Roboto-regular', 12), fg='black')
message.pack()

entry_message = tk.Entry(r, width=45)
entry_message.pack()

enter_hour = tk.Label(r, text='Enter the hour for the alarm to go off: ',
                        font=('Roboto-regular', 12), fg='black')
enter_hour.pack()

entry_hour = tk.Entry(r, width=10)
entry_hour.pack()

enter_minute = tk.Label(r, text='Enter the minute for the alarm to go off: ',
                        font=('Roboto-regular', 12), fg='black')
enter_minute.pack()

entry_minute = tk.Entry(r, width=10)
entry_minute.pack()

enter_second = tk.Label(r, text='Enter the second for the alarm to go off: ',
                    font=('Roboto-regular', 12), fg='black')
enter_second.pack()

entry_second = tk.Entry(r, width=10)
entry_second.pack()

text_label = tk.Label(r, font=('Roboto-regular', 12, 'bold'),  fg='tomato')
text_label.pack()

submit_button = tk.Button(r, text='Submit',
                          fg='black', width=30, height=2, relief='groove',
                          cursor='hand2', command=display_output)
submit_button.pack()

snooze_button = tk.Button(r, text='Snooze alarm',
                          fg='black',
                          width=30, height=2, relief='groove',
                          cursor='hand2', command=end)
snooze_button.pack()

r.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can see Submit button when I run code in my answer - so I don;t know what problem you have. Did you run it console/terminal/cmd.exe to see if you get any error message ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. This has helped me. Edit: I did not see the button, but added it myself and now it works properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `while True:` loop, use a function and register a callback for the function every 'specified interval' of time. This is done in the code below:

```py
def wait_for_alarm():
    after = r.after(1000, wait_for_alarm)  # 1000 refers to 1 second
    if time.localtime().tm_hour == hr and time.localtime().tm_min == mn and time.localtime().tm_sec == sc:
        print(message)
        alarm_Sound()
        mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! But Python gives a SyntaxError: break outside loop.

Comment: Oh yeah, you don't need break anymore. @BoAnonymous edited to correct that, thanks

Comment: No problem, thank you very much for the quick replies. I'm going to play with this code now.